# PureComponent decorated by mobx-react throws error about `shouldComponentUpdate` presence

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, react-16

In console I see this warning:

> index.js:2178 Warning: Body has a method called
>   shouldComponentUpdate(). shouldComponentUpdate should not be used when
>   extending React.PureComponent. Please extend React.Component if
>   shouldComponentUpdate is used.

`Body` component is using

```
...
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
...
@inject('store')
@observer
class Body extends React.PureComponent<BodyProps> {
...
```

but doesn't have this `shouldComponentUpdate` method anywhere.

**Is this coming from `mobx-react`? Can I use `PureComponent` in components decorated by `@observable` or `@inject` ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PureComponents should not be used in combination with `observer`. Conceptually it is strange as observer makes components impure; as they can update without prop changes (which is actually the whole point of observer).

The upcoming mobx-react version will warn about this :)

Comment: So this observer puts shouldComponentUpdate in the code?

Comment: Observer, observable -> when a property changes, call forceUpdate( ). This bypasses shouldComponentUpdate( ), which can still be used to skip re-rendering when props change. I don't understand why mobx is doing this.

Comment: @mweststrate  The readme of the mobx-react recommends to extend React.PureComponent (Link below). I followed these recommendation and run into this error.

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/tree/main/packages/mobx-react#class-components